# luatex node library: replace glyph with hlist containing glyph

Tags: luatex, lua, node-library

While trying to replace glyph node with a hlist containing the glyph I was expecting to see the same output on the line, but I see boxes overlap, and get a `pdf backend` warning. Here, the warning message, screenshot, and complete code:

```
warning  (pdf backend): forcing bad dir -1 to TLT in synch_pos_with_cur

warning  (pdf backend): ignoring bad dir -1 when outputting a character
.
.
.
```

Screenshot:
[image: hlist overlap]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2in,right=2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\directlua{
    function my_post_lb_filter(head,groupcode)
      local linenumber=1;
      local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
      local GLYPH = node.id("glyph")
      for n in node.traverse(head) do
        if n.id==HLIST then
          if linenumber==3 then
            for g in node.traverse(n.head) do
              if g.id == GLYPH then
                print("character: " .. string.utfcharacter(g.char))
                local gc = node.copy(g);
                local hbox = node.new(HLIST);
                hbox.head = node.insert_after(hbox.list,hbox.head,gc)
                n.head = node.insert_after(n.list,g,hbox)
                n.head = node.remove(n.head,g)
              end
            end
          end
        linenumber=linenumber+1;
        end
      end
      return head
    end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', my_post_lb_filter, 'Play with luatex node library')
}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The width of a hlist is the value of the width field and not the width of it's content. Given that you do not use `node.hpack` or similar which automatically calculates the width, it gets initialized to zero. So all hlists have width zero, leading to overlap. The warning is a similar issue: You never set the direction, so LuaTeX isn't sure which direction to use.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Trying to learn node library. Here the intent is to learn how to replace existing nodes with new ones (that potentially have contents copied from the nodes being removed). The motivation is similar to the author of chickenize package: do it to learn it...

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Also, as per your suggestion, I replaced the line that does node_insertafter with `local hpack = node.hpack(hbox); n.head = node.insert_after(n.list,g,hpack)`, but the output is still the same: overlapping glyphs, and pdf backend warning. Even if I add `hpack.width = g.width` (which is not ideal, I would want any random content in the hlist that I don't know the width of), the pdf backend warning still stays (while the output looks fine, meaning the glyphs don't overlap) Why does hpack not calculate the width automatically, and why still the pdf backend warning?

Comment: `local hpack = node.hpack(hbox)` creates an additional hlist around `hbox` with automatically calculated width (which happens to be `0` because the list only contains a single hbox which still has width 0. You want to replace `local hbox = ... hbox.head = ...` with `local hbox = node.hpack(gc)` instead. Also, you still didn't set the direction.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, how about this: `local hbox = node.hpack(gc,0,"additional",n.dir)` I try to inherit direction from outer hlist.